# Matlab Codgen: Build error: 'lcclnk64' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

This question is on error occurring while  C code generation from MATLAB Script.

I want to convert my MATLAB script to standalone executable file. When I ran my file (Code_check.m) with 'codegen' command I got following error in *target build log*:

**'lcclnk64' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file gmake: * [Code_Check_mex.mexw64] Error 1**

There are other lines in target build log, commands which probably show build of c file for matlab commands (like randi,fprintf etc.)

I have checked script with %#codegen inclusion and it gives no error. While running with codegen, above mentioned error occurs. I have checked if matlab path is included in system variables path, and it is. So I have no clue how to go on.

Can somebody give some insight on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

My .m script is as follows: (I apologize for long question)

```
% code
%#codegen
function [Output]  = Code_Check
data = coder.load('EMEA_code_prep.mat');
temp_wt = find(data.Wash_cycle_data( randi(2131), : ));
fileID = fopen('Results.txt','w');
if length(  find(data.Wash_cycle_data( randi(2131), : ))  ) == 1;
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Wash cycle type');
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n',data.Wash_type(temp_wt,:));
else
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Wash cycle type');
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','N/A for this trial');
end
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Speen Speed');
temp_SP = data.un_SP(find(data.idx_SP( randi(2131), : )));
fprintf(fileID,'%12.8f\n',temp_SP(1)  );
temp_temp_ll =  find(  data.Loading_level_data( randi(2131),: )   );
if  length(temp_temp_ll) == 1
Output(2,3) = Loading_level(temp_temp_ll);
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Loading Level');
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n',data.Loading_level(temp_temp_ll,:));
elseif length(temp_temp_ll) == 0
%Output(2,3) = NAvar;   
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Loading Level');
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','N/A');
else
temp_temp = data.Loading_level(temp_temp_ll);    
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Loading Level');
fprintf(fileID,'%40s\n',temp_temp(1));
end
temp_temp_f =  find(  data.Fabric_type_data( randi(2131),: )   );
if  length(temp_temp_f) == 1
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Fabric Type');
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n',data.Fabric_type(temp_temp_f,:));
elseif length(temp_temp_f) == 0
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Fabric Type');
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','N/A');
else
temp_temp = data.Fabric_type(temp_temp_f);    
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Fabric Type');
fprintf(fileID,'%40s\n',temp_temp(1));
end

temp_temp_c = find(data.Color_data( randi(2131),: )   );
if length(temp_temp_c) == 1  
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Color');
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n',data.Color(temp_temp_c,:));
elseif length(temp_temp_c) == 0
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Color');
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','N/A');
else 
temp_temp = data.Color(temp_temp_c);    
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Color');
fprintf(fileID,'%40s\n',temp_temp(1));
end
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Wash Results');
temp_WR = data.un_Wresults(find(data.idx_Wresults( randi(131), : )));
fprintf(fileID,'%12.8f\n',temp_WR(1));
fprintf(fileID,'%20s\n','Wash Results');
temp_Spr = data.un_Spresults(find(data.idx_Wresults( randi(131), : )));
fprintf(fileID,'%12.8f\n',temp_Spr(1));
Output = data.Title;
end
```

and Last few lines of target build log:

```
14   lcclnk64 -dll -L"C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2014b\sys\lcc64\lcc64\lib64" -        L"C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2014b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft" -entry LibMain "Code_Check_mex_lccstub.obj" -s -o Code_Check_mex.mexw64  Code_Check_mexutil.obj Code_Check_data.obj Code_Check_initialize.obj Code_Check_terminate.obj Code_Check.obj randi.obj fopen.obj fileManager.obj fprintf.obj  _coder_Code_Check_api.obj _coder_Code_Check_mex.obj _coder_Code_Check_info.obj  libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib  libemlrt.lib libcovrt.lib libut.lib  libmwblas.lib libmwmathutil.lib Code_Check_mex_mex.def
15   'lcclnk64' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
16   operable program or batch file.
17   gmake: *** [Code_Check_mex.mexw64] Error 1
```

Comment: Looks like you need LCC compiler, http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/

Comment: Actually, lcc-win64 is [shipped with MATLAB R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014b/index.html?sec=win64#matlab).  You should check if the file: `[matlabroot, '\sys\lcc64\lcc64\bin\lcclnk64.exe']` is present on your system. Was the compiler called successfully? Just the linker fails? You could also consider installing another supported compiler from the link above. The Windows SDK 7.1 is free and supported in R2014b.